# Difference between roslaunch and rosrun with image_view

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If I run:

```
rosrun image_view stereo_view stereo:=raw_stereo image:=image_rect _approximate_sync:=true
```

I see the correct left and right channels of my stereo camera and a stereo depth map.

However, if I use roslaunch to run the equivalent launch file:

```
<launch>
    <node name="stereo_view" pkg="image_view" type="stereo_view">
        <param name="stereo" value="raw_stereo" />
        <param name="image" value="image_rect" />
        <param name="_approximate_sync" value="true" />
    </node>
</launch>
```

all I see are gray screens. What is the difference in the launch file that causes it to fail?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/209035/difference-between-roslaunch-and-rosrun-with-image_view/) by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 940 on 2015-05-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's caused by the usage of rosrun:

To set parameters when calling a node with ros run the syntax is:

```
rosrun package node _parameter:=value
```

To remap a topic when calling a node with ros run the syntax is:

```
rosrun package node topic_name:=remapped_topic_name
```

Note the lack of `_` prefix before the topic_name!
(See: http://wiki.ros.org/rosbash#rosrun  )

Therefore in the example you've given `stereo` and `image` are topics and `approximate_sync` is a parameter. Hence, you cannot set `stereo` and `image` as parameters in the roslaunch, you must use the remap tag (See http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/remap ). I think the correct launch equivalent would be something like:

```
<launch>
    <node name="stereo_view" pkg="image_view" type="stereo_view">
        <remap from="stereo" to="raw_stereo" />
        <remap from="image" to="image_rect" />
        <param name="approximate_sync" value="true" />
    </node>
</launch>
```

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2015-05-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3